# Probleme for using PCL 1.6.0 on VS2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, hyperlink, point-cloud-library

I'm trying to some 3D stuff with PCL 1.6.0 on Visual studio 2010 x64.

I've started my coding : `  pcl::PointCloud::Ptr cloud (new pcl::PointCloud);

```
int iRet = pcl::io::loadPCDFile<pcl::PointXYZ>("fileout.pcd", *cloud);

boost::shared_ptr<pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer> viewer (new pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer( "3D Viewer"));

viewer->setBackgroundColor(0, 0,0);

//viewer->addPointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>(cloud, "sample cloud");`
```

When I compile this code, it is ok no problem.

But when i try to compile with the commented line, I've serveral external non resolvable symbols

Thanks for you help.
F.

> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "protected: __cdecl vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(class vtkObjectBase *,class vtkSmartPointerBase::NoReference const &)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@IEAA@PEAVvtkObjectBase@@AEBVNoReference@0@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "protected: __cdecl vtkSmartPointer::vtkSmartPointer(class vtkPoints *,class vtkSmartPointerBase::NoReference const &)" (??0?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkPoints@@@@IEAA@PEAVvtkPoints@@AEBVNoReference@vtkSmartPointerBase@@@Z)    C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: __cdecl vtkSmartPointerBase::~vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??1vtkSmartPointerBase@@QEAA@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: __cdecl vtkSmartPointer::~vtkSmartPointer(void)" (??1?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkPoints@@@@QEAA@XZ)  C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: __cdecl vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(class vtkObjectBase *)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@QEAA@PEAVvtkObjectBase@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: __cdecl vtkSmartPointer::vtkSmartPointer(class vtkSmartPointer const &)" (??$?0VvtkPolyData@@@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkDataSet@@@@QEAA@AEBV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkPolyData@@@@@Z)  C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: __cdecl vtkSmartPointerBase::vtkSmartPointerBase(void)" (??0vtkSmartPointerBase@@QEAA@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: __cdecl vtkSmartPointer::vtkSmartPointer(void)" (??0?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkLODActor@@@@QEAA@XZ) C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: class vtkCellArray * __cdecl vtkPolyData::GetVerts(void)" (?GetVerts@vtkPolyData@@QEAAPEAVvtkCellArray@@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "private: void __cdecl pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::convertPointCloudToVTKPolyData(class pcl::visualization::PointCloudGeometryHandler const &,class vtkSmartPointer &,class vtkSmartPointer &)" (??$convertPointCloudToVTKPolyData@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@PCLVisualizer@visualization@pcl@@AEAAXAEBV?$PointCloudGeometryHandler@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@12@AEAV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkPolyData@@@@AEAV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkIdTypeArray@@@@@Z)  C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: class vtkSmartPointerBase & __cdecl vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(class vtkObjectBase *)" (??4vtkSmartPointerBase@@QEAAAEAV0@PEAVvtkObjectBase@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: class vtkSmartPointer & __cdecl vtkSmartPointer::operator=(class vtkSmartPointer const &)" (??$?4VvtkUnsignedCharArray@@@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkDataArray@@@@QEAAAEAV0@AEBV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkUnsignedCharArray@@@@@Z)  C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: class vtkSmartPointerBase & __cdecl vtkSmartPointerBase::operator=(class vtkSmartPointerBase const &)" (??4vtkSmartPointerBase@@QEAAAEAV0@AEBV0@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: class vtkSmartPointer & __cdecl vtkSmartPointer::operator=(class vtkSmartPointer const &)" (??4?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkPoints@@@@QEAAAEAV0@AEBV0@@Z)  C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: int __cdecl vtkDataSetAttributes::SetScalars(class vtkDataArray *)" (?SetScalars@vtkDataSetAttributes@@QEAAHPEAVvtkDataArray@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "private: bool __cdecl pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::fromHandlersToScreen(class pcl::visualization::PointCloudGeometryHandler const &,class pcl::visualization::PointCloudColorHandler const &,class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > const &,int,class Eigen::Matrix const &,class Eigen::Quaternion const &)" (??$fromHandlersToScreen@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@PCLVisualizer@visualization@pcl@@AEAA_NAEBV?$PointCloudGeometryHandler@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@12@AEBV?$PointCloudColorHandler@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@12@AEBV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@HAEBV?$Matrix@M$03$00$0A@$03$00@Eigen@@AEBV?$Quaternion@M$0A@@8@@Z) C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: static class vtkCellArray * __cdecl vtkCellArray::New(void)" (?New@vtkCellArray@@SAPEAV1@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: static class vtkSmartPointer __cdecl vtkSmartPointer::New(void)" (?New@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkCellArray@@@@SA?AV1@XZ)  C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: static class vtkFloatArray * __cdecl vtkFloatArray::New(void)" (?New@vtkFloatArray@@SAPEAV1@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: static class vtkSmartPointer __cdecl vtkSmartPointer::New(void)" (?New@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkFloatArray@@@@SA?AV1@XZ)    C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: static class vtkMatrix4x4 * __cdecl vtkMatrix4x4::New(void)" (?New@vtkMatrix4x4@@SAPEAV1@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: static class vtkSmartPointer __cdecl vtkSmartPointer::New(void)" (?New@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkMatrix4x4@@@@SA?AV1@XZ)  C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: static class vtkPoints * __cdecl vtkPoints::New(void)" (?New@vtkPoints@@SAPEAV1@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: static class vtkSmartPointer __cdecl vtkSmartPointer::New(void)" (?New@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkPoints@@@@SA?AV1@XZ)    C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: static class vtkUnsignedCharArray * __cdecl vtkUnsignedCharArray::New(void)" (?New@vtkUnsignedCharArray@@SAPEAV1@XZ) référencé dans la fonction "public: static class vtkSmartPointer __cdecl vtkSmartPointer::New(void)" (?New@?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkUnsignedCharArray@@@@SA?AV1@XZ)  C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: void __cdecl vtkCellArray::SetCells(__int64,class vtkIdTypeArray *)" (?SetCells@vtkCellArray@@QEAAX_JPEAVvtkIdTypeArray@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "private: void __cdecl pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::convertPointCloudToVTKPolyData(class pcl::visualization::PointCloudGeometryHandler const &,class vtkSmartPointer &,class vtkSmartPointer &)" (??$convertPointCloudToVTKPolyData@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@PCLVisualizer@visualization@pcl@@AEAAXAEBV?$PointCloudGeometryHandler@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@12@AEAV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkPolyData@@@@AEAV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkIdTypeArray@@@@@Z) C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: void __cdecl vtkDataArrayTemplate::SetArray(float *,__int64,int,int)" (?SetArray@?$vtkDataArrayTemplate@M@@QEAAXPEAM_JHH@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: void __cdecl vtkDataArrayTemplate::SetArray(float *,__int64,int)" (?SetArray@?$vtkDataArrayTemplate@M@@QEAAXPEAM_JH@Z)   C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: void __cdecl vtkDataArrayTemplate::SetArray(unsigned char *,__int64,int,int)" (?SetArray@?$vtkDataArrayTemplate@E@@QEAAXPEAE_JHH@Z) référencé dans la fonction "public: void __cdecl vtkDataArrayTemplate::SetArray(unsigned char *,__int64,int)" (?SetArray@?$vtkDataArrayTemplate@E@@QEAAXPEAE_JH@Z)    C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL
>
> Error LNK2019: symbole externe non résolu "public: void __cdecl vtkPolyData::SetVerts(class vtkCellArray *)" (?SetVerts@vtkPolyData@@QEAAXPEAVvtkCellArray@@@Z) référencé dans la fonction "private: void __cdecl pcl::visualization::PCLVisualizer::convertPointCloudToVTKPolyData(class pcl::visualization::PointCloudGeometryHandler const &,class vtkSmartPointer &,class vtkSmartPointer &)" (??$convertPointCloudToVTKPolyData@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@PCLVisualizer@visualization@pcl@@AEAAXAEBV?$PointCloudGeometryHandler@UPointXYZ@pcl@@@12@AEAV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkPolyData@@@@AEAV?$vtkSmartPointer@VvtkIdTypeArray@@@@@Z) C:\Users\8310706B\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\TestPCL\icpmain.obj TestPCL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is an undefined reference/unresolved external symbol error and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix)

Comment: Not really. I know that some *.lib are missing. But Even if i link with all vtk libraries, I've still undefined symbols.

Answer (score 0):

If you are under windows and during install PCL, you have "PATH Too long" error message,

The libs list are (for debug compiling) :

> pcl_visualization_debug.lib pcl_common_debug.lib pcl_apps_debug.lib
>   pcl_features_debug.lib pcl_filters_debug.lib pcl_io_debug.lib
>   pcl_io_ply_debug.lib pcl_kdtree_debug.lib pcl_keypoints_debug.lib
>   pcl_octree_debug.lib pcl_registration_debug.lib
>   pcl_sample_consensus_debug.lib pcl_search_debug.lib
>   pcl_segmentation_debug.lib pcl_surface_debug.lib
>   pcl_tracking_debug.lib vtkHybrid-gd.lib vtkalglib-gd.lib
>   vtkCharts-gd.lib vtkCommon-gd.lib vtkIO-gd.lib vtksys-gd.lib
>   vtkViews-gd.lib vtkWidgets-gd.lib vtkVolumeRendering-gd.lib
>   vtkzlib-gd.lib vtkfreetype-gd.lib MapReduceMPI-gd.lib vtkexoIIc-gd.lib
>   vtkImaging-gd.lib vtkInfovis-gd.lib vtkjpeg-gd.lib vtklibxml2-gd.lib
>   vtkpng-gd.lib vtkproj4-gd.lib vtkRendering.lib vtkverdict-gd.lib
>   vtksqlite-gd.lib mpistubs-gd.lib QVTK-gd.lib vtkDICOMParser-gd.lib
>   vtkexpat-gd.lib vtkFiltering-gd.lib